# Filter elements that have a particular class as ancestor

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery snippet that opens all outbound links in a new window.

```
jQuery(document.links)
    .filter(function() {
        return this.hostname != window.location.hostname;
    })
    .attr('target', '_blank');
```

That works just fine.

I am trying to make this NOT work for any links that appear inside of element with class `.render` (may or may not be the immediate parent).

I've tried:

```
jQuery(document.links)
    .filter(function() {
        return this.hostname != window.location.hostname;
    })
    .not( this.parents('.render'))
    .attr('target', '_blank');
```

Not only does that not work, the console says that `parents` is not a function.

Comment: Do you need $(this).parents()?

Comment: that won't work because at that point "this" is not referring to the link. Also the poster's original intent, while valid, could be very slow if since each link test would be re-creating a set of all the links under .render

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var renderLinks = jQuery(".render a");
jQuery(a).filter(...).not(renderLinks).attr('target', function(){ return '_blank';});
```

Comment: or simpler and less overhead `not(".render a")`

Comment: quite right. was thinking I'd need another filter function and remembered not just takes a jQuery object

Comment: I'm marking this correct, but I just inserted `.not('render a')` into my original. Thanks!

Comment: actually you'd probably be more efficient with `.not($('.render a'))` because the list of .render a links would only be assembled once. That was what I was trying to show in my original code.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are already using one filter there is no need to add another with `not()` . Just add extra condition inside `filter()`

```
jQuery('a').filter(function() {
  var hostMatch = this.hostname != window.location.hostname,
    isRenderItem = $(this).closest(".render").length;
  return hostMatch && !isRenderItem;
}).attr('target', '_blank');
```

Comment: This generates an error:
Uncaught ReferenceError: a is not defined

Comment: should be string `'a'`

Comment: besides of which this approach is very inefficient. Depending on how your DOM is constructed (which we don't know and is subject to change). At the very least there is an extra jQuery object generated for every a element.